# Ajax Response Json data, are not always valid

Tags: json, ajax, response

My website is using ajax calls to add products to cart. Each time a customer presses "Add to Cart" button, there's an ajax request called. The Json data response is sometimes not valid or not formed correctly.

Using firefox developer tools, here's the response data in both ways:

Normal json response:
[image: The correct json response]

Not valid json data response:
[image: Not valid json data response]

1) What kind of issue is this?
2) Why is this happening in some cases and not other cases? Could it be the data itself causing this?
3) Possible solutions to this?

Comment: Please add both client and server side code. Otherwise it is impossible to answer any of your questions.

Comment: Go to `jsonviewer.stack.hu` and paste the response and validate if it is a proper json or not. It may be that your server doesn't escape some values propertly

Comment: show your server side code

Comment: actually seems theres no problem. possibly you must tell the ajax function that the datatype is json. the console in the clip you show has a string logged

Comment: Have you tried setting the header to content type application/json? For ex in PHP you have use `header('Content-type:application/json');` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are two possible cases where browser can't parse JSON data:

1. Wrong Content-Type header
2. Malformed JSON string

In your case, as it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't it's probably the second one. There must be some characters in your response that are escaped in your server side code which are not valid in browser. All server side language have options when converting objects to JSON strings. you can check the invalid response in a JSON linter like https://jsonlint.com/ to see which part causes the problem then search for options to disable this behaviour in your server side code.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What kind of issue is this?

Server side issue.

> 2) Why is this happening in some cases and not other cases?

Bad logic in the server side backend code.

> Could it be the data itself causing this?

No

> 3) Possible solutions to this?

Fix the server side code's logic.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the datatype of your Ajax function is JSON and you should check your server side code, perhaps the response is not well formatted.

Answer (score 1):

the problem in you post  parameters sometimes sending value or sometimes not check the code of javascript and server code as well for validation.